# Remove same elements from multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, spyder

I am using Python and I have a bunch of columns that got added some symbols.

So if a column once was "A" it now says "('A', '')". So I need to remove (' and ', ''). Some variables (400 to be more precise) should have been called "1 A" but are called "('A', 1)". So for these I need to remove (' and ', ) and move the number to the front of A. They became like that after a pivot_table command.

So I need to go from before to after:

```
data_before = {"('A', '')" : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
               "('B', '')" : ['p', 'o', 'n'],
               "('C', 1)"  : [1, 1, 1], 
               "('C', 2)"  : [1, 2, 1], 
               "('D', 1)"  : [1, 2, 4],
               "('D', 2)"  : [1, 5, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_before)

data_after = {'A'    : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
              'B'    : ['p', 'o', 'n'],
              '1 C'  : [1, 1, 1], 
              '2 C'  : [1, 2, 1], 
              '1 D'  : [1, 2, 4],
              '2 D'  : [1, 5, 3]}

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_after)
```

Keep in mind that there are 42 variables that look like C and D and they each go from 1 to 10 (not just 2), so there are 420 columns. I don't want to write each of them down manually to change the name. Only the 3 first variables look like A and B. (423 columns in total).

Update to accommodate for more letters and numbers. So 1 C, 2 C... 10 C and 1 Z, 2 Z ... 10 Z.

```
data_before = {"('A', '')" : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
               "('B', '')" : ['p', 'o', 'n'],
               "('C', 1)"  : [1, 1, 1], 
               "('C', 2)"  : [1, 2, 1], 
               "('C', 3)"  : [3, 2, 1], 
               "('D', 1)"  : [1, 2, 3],
               "('D', 2)"  : [1, 2, 3],
               "('D', 3)"  : [1, 2, 3],
               "('E', 1)"  : [1, 1, 1], 
               "('E', 2)"  : [1, 2, 1], 
               "('E', 3)"  : [3, 2, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_before)

data_after = {'A'    : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
              'B'    : ['p', 'o', 'n'],
              '1 C'  : [1, 1, 1], 
              '2 C'  : [1, 2, 1], 
              '3 C'  : [3, 2, 1], 
              '1 D'  : [1, 2, 3], 
              '2 D'  : [1, 2, 3],
              '3 D'  : [1, 2, 3]
              '1 E'  : [1, 1, 1], 
              '2 E'  : [1, 2, 1],
              '3 E'  : [3, 2, 1]}

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_after)
```

This command:

```
df.columns = [f'{b} {a}'.strip() for a, b in df.columns]
```

Returns:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Fixed it for you.

Comment: Does my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are tuples or `MultiIndex` is possible use `f-strings` with `strip`:

```
data_before = {('A', '') : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
               ('B', '') : ['p', 'o', 'n'],
               ('C', 1) : [1, 1, 1], 
               ('C', 2)  : [1, 2, 1], 
               ('D', 1)  : [1, 2, np.NaN],
               ('D', 2)  : [1, np.NaN, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_before)

df.columns = [f'{b} {a}'.strip() for a, b in df.columns]
print (df)
   A  B  1 C  2 C  1 D  2 D
0  a  p    1    1  1.0  1.0
1  b  o    1    2  2.0  NaN
2  c  n    1    1  NaN  3.0
```

EDIT:

```
import ast

df.columns = [f'{b} {a}'.strip() for a, b in df.columns.map(ast.literal_eval)]

print (df)
   A  B  1 C  2 C  3 C  1 D  2 D  3 D  1 E  2 E  3 E
0  a  p    1    1    3    1    1    1    1    1    3
1  b  o    1    2    2    2    2    2    1    2    2
2  c  n    1    1    1    3    3    3    1    1    1
```

Comment: That worked for me, but to make the solution complete the 1's and 2's should also be moved to the front of the letters. @jezrael

Comment: The part about the changing location works if you have C 1, C 2 for example, but what if it goes up to 10 and you have the whole alphabet? 
I get this error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) @jezrael

Comment: @nielsen - then what is logic here? Do you need sorting them?

Comment: I can't see the number when working with the data, and it provides better overview for when presenting it.

Comment: @nielsen - numbers are always last value?

Comment: @nielsen - Answer was edited with last value of tuples to start of new columns names, how working with real data?

Comment: When I said it goes up to 10, I meant, C 1, C 2, C 3 ... C 10 and with the whole alpha bet i meant that theres also D 1,.. D 10 ... Z 1,... Z10. I'm so sorry for not being clear enough. @jezrael. And yes numbers are always last value except for the first 3 variables that don't have a number.

Comment: @nielsen - Is possible change `data_before = {('A', '') : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
               ('B', '') : ['p', 'o', 'n'],
               ('C', 1) : [1, 1, 1], 
               ('C', 2)  : [1, 2, 1], 
               ('D', 1)  : [1, 2, np.NaN],
               ('D', 2)  : [1, np.NaN, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_before)` for better data for see why first my solution not working ?

Comment: @nielsen - I am a bit confused, there are tuples? Or strings? `print (type(df.columns[0]))` is `tuple` ?

Comment: print (type(df.columns[0])) is a string

Comment: @nielsen - EDIT was changed, can you test?

Comment: I get error: ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x0000019CD33AF448>

Comment: @nielsen - hmmm, so data problem? Data are extracted from file? Or do you pivot dataframe?

Comment: But listen, I really appreciate the help. It works for my mwe and I can't expect more from you. I think I will try making every last letter of all my columns into a row, and then removing the ones that dont need a letter and then applying that row to the front of all columns. Yes it was a result from a pivot.

Comment: @nielsen - No problem, thank you. If data are read from file with tuples in columns it is not easy, but if you convert df columns to tuples, then there is hope for betetr solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to remove all the useless characters first, and then you split and reverse the string.

```
import re 
df.columns = [" ".join(reversed(re.sub(r"\)|\(|'|,", "", x).split()))
              for x in df.columns]
```

Comment: This works for the data at hand. It's a really good solution. I keep realising that my mwe is not good enough. The letters A, B, C, D, E.. represent names that are longer in my data, and there this solution does not seem to work. But I will give it a "solved" cause it works here.